# Weird behavior on Microsoft Access 2013 with navigation form and subreport

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form named formName with a combo control named idFilter and a subreport named subReportName.
What I want to do is when I change the value in idFilter, the content in the subReportName filtered according to the value in idFilter. And I have achieved this by the following code on formName:

```
private sub idFilter_change()
    Me.subReportName.report.filter = "id = """ & me.idFilter.value &""""
    Me.subReportName.report.filteron = true
End sub
```

This piece of code works fine when I open the formName as standalone. But once I put formName into an navigation form, then the weird behavior occurs: every time I change the value in idFilter, it returns runtime error 2467 "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exists" on this line of code:

```
Me.subReportName.report.filteron = true
```

What's more, the value in idFilter is not what I have changed.
What am I missing? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an inbuilt navigation form, then your form reference isn't correct.

The inbuilt navigation forms are actually tabbed forms loaded on click.

Try making your own form for ease of use, or have a look at this thread for some examples https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=223306