# Form Inside Navigation Form Causing Weird Behavior When Using ComboBox to Filter Report?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a `ComboBox` filter sitting above a `Report`. The form is contained inside a Tabbed Navigation form. It looks something like this:

[image]

The `ComboBox` is UNBOUND and contains a list of values that I can filter the report with. I've written some vba code that looks something like this:

```
Private Sub comboBox_FilterField_AfterUpdate()

    Me.subreport_TestReport.Report.Filter = "ID = " & Me.comboBox_FilterField

    Me.subreport_TestReport.Report.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

The **first problem** is, as soon as I select a value from the `ComboBox`, I get an error:

[image]

The **second problem** is, the value selected in the `ComboBox` is not the value stored after the call to `AfterUpdate` is completed, but instead the value store is the previous value selected, i.e. if I start with no values in the `ComboBox` and select `1`, the `ComboBox` stores a `Blank` space. Now if I select `2`, the `ComboBox` stores `1`, etc.

This is exactly the same issue as this person had:

[Weird behavior on Microsoft Access 2013 with navigation form and subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972957/weird-behavior-on-microsoft-access-2013-with-navigation-form-and-subreport)

What is causing these issues?

Comment: I think in a form you can't use report (I am not sure). Then it should be subform then could would be `Me.subreport_TestReport.Form.Filter = "ID = " & Me.comboBox_FilterField`

Comment: I commented in your other question (now deleted) and could not replicate issue but you did not indicate a Navigation Form was involved. I avoid them because they can be difficult to code (as you are discovering). @Harun24HR, a report can sit on a form. And no, it would `Me.subreport_TestReport.Report.Filter`.

Comment: @June7 apology, I deleted it to add more details. I should've edited it instead but my fingers were too quick. Unfortunately I cannot avoid a Navigation Form because there's functionality in other tabs, and would require more time to re-factor. Any way to resolve this with Navigation Form used?

Comment: @June7 I didn't try it yet to put a form on form. so, I am not sure. Thanks for information.

Comment: I find code filters without error once and then errors on the FilterOn line. If I first click on the navigation tab before selecting in combobox, I don't get error. Unfortunately, I can't find method to code this. DoCmd.BrowseTo doesn't help.

Comment: I suspect this is because a report cannot be filtered once it is open.
Try reloading the report object with the filter set or set the filter condition in the open report event.

Comment: As already commented, the filtering works and on normal form there is no issue but Navigation Form causes complication.

Comment: @Minty as June7 mentioned, the filtering works and the report filters, but Navigation Form causes issues as I mentioned in the OP. I'm still trying to figure out how to resolve this with Navigation Form.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly error 2467 has nothing to do with the navigation form.  Given the information you provided I wasn't able to replicate the second problem.   Reports are used for printing so it is very unusual to see a sub-report in a form.  However replacing the report with a form will still fail because the problem is you are filtering incorrectly.  On the subreport properties window under the data tab there are link master and link child properties.  These properties are set automatically if you use drag and drop to add the sub-report to the form.  When these properties are set you filter the main form and the changes cascade to the sub-report. so:

```
'instead of
Me.subformName.Form.Filter = "Whatever"
'use
Me.Filter = "Whatever"

'Then call
Me.FilterOn = True
```

If for some reason you want to manually filter the subform like the subform is based on unrelated data then Make sure the master and child links are not set and then you   can filter the sub-report manually with:

```
Me.subformName.Form.Filter = "Whatever"
Me.subformName.Form.FilterOn = True
```

as for the second error you may have done something unusual when setting up the combobox.  Google Access Filter Form Combo Box and watch a few videos.

Comment: In regards to your first suggestion how do I re-link it if it's blank, and which fields do I link it to? Maybe that will solve another issue I have.

Comment: Assuming a 1 teacher and many students relationship between a Teacher table and Student table.  Generally to filter the students by teacher put teacherID from the the Teacher table in the master and teacherid from the student table in the child.  In this example the combobox would have 2 columns: teacherid & teacherName.  The bound column is teacherid with a width of 0 so all you see is the helpful teacherName but cmbFilterbyTeacher value will be teacherid so Me.Filter = "teacherid = " & cmbFilterbyTeacher makes sense.  In other words look for spelling and logic errors in your code.