# Refresh All VBA Code Equivalent to Refresh Data in Form from another form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a `Form` that is linked to a `Query`. In this form, each row contains a hyperlink value that opens another `Form` containing the data of that row. The data obtained in the **secondary** form is executed like (below code is in secondary form):

```
Public Sub Form_Load()
   
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord acTable, "Secondary_Form", acFirst, "[Field1] = " & TempVars!currentRec

End Sub
```

The parent form contains the following code upon clicking the hyperlink field value for a particular record:

```
Public Sub Field1_Click()
   TempVars.Add "currentRec", "" & [Field1]

   DoCmd.openForm "Secondary_Form", acNormal, "", "", , acDialog
End Sub
```

In the secondary form containing the details of the record, I have a "Close" button with the following event, that upon closing the data, "should" refresh the parent form with any changes made from the secondary form, but it doesn't:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

   CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"
   DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name

End Sub
```

Since the main form is linked to a Query, which is linked to a Table, I have verified that changes in the secondary form to the record is reflected in the Table, and thus in the Query as well. However, the only way I can get the parent form to reflect the changes made in the secondary form is to manually hit the **Refresh All** in the **Home** tab.

I've also tried to open the parent form (even though it's already opened behind the secondary form), and run a `Requery` and `Refresh`, which had no result in updating the main form with the changes of the record:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

   Dim fm As Form

   DoCmd.openForm "Main_Form", acNormal

   Set fm = Forms("Main_Form")

   fm.Requery
   fm.Refresh

   DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name

End Sub
```

How can I refresh the main form using VBA code instead of manually clicking "Refresh All"?

Comment: Are you sure the data is changed before, and not after refreshing the form? Do you have code updating the data before the requery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requery the main form when code returns after closing the secondary form:

```vb
Public Sub Field1_Click()

   TempVars.Add "currentRec", "" & [Field1]
   DoCmd.openForm "Secondary_Form", acNormal, "", "", , acDialog
   ' Seconday Form closes.
   Me.Requery

End Sub
```

No need to reopen the main form as it hasn't been closed:

```vb
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

   DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand neither one of your code provided. `Field1_Click()` is in the main form and this function is called upon clicking the column `Field1` in the main form, which opens the secondary form, through `DoCmd.OpenForm`. How does `Me.Requery` help refresh the main form if you don't know when the secondary form is closed yet? Secondly, the `Cancel_Click()` is in the secondary form, and the code just simply closes the secondary form. This is where the handling of refreshing the main form should be done.

Comment: No . Code in the main form is halted at `  ' Seconday Form closes.` while the secondary form is held open, and does not proceed until the secondary form has been closed, opened in _Dialogue_ mode as it is.

Comment: works perfectly. Can you happen to inspect my other issue posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493444/form-inside-navigation-form-causing-weird-behavior-when-using-combobox-to-filter?noredirect=1#comment122843583_69493444

Comment: Sorry, I avoid navigation forms - to not encounter issues like that of yours.